# Windows - How can I check if I am really mining ETH or not?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethminer

I'm trying to mine ETH on windows wit ATI GPU.
I made these steps:

1. Downloaded `geth` and put it into a folder `../ethereum/geth`
2. Downloaded `ethminer` and put it into `../ethereum/ethminer`
3. I run command `geth account new` and set password
4. I run command `geth --rpc --fast --cache=1024`
5. I run (into another cmd window)

`setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
ethminer.exe -G --cl-global-work 16834 --cl-local-work 256`

In the cmd windows it started to print the hash rate and other data.

Now, I want to ask you: how can I check if everything is ok?

(eg. "I miss something?", "Am I mining on the correct wallet address?", "How I earned?" etc.)

Answer (score 1):

An indirect way to do it is to check your balance.
If it's non zero that means you are mining.

An easy way to do that is search for your account number at https://etherchain.org
and take a look at the balance.

However, if you are solo mining (and it looks like you do), I am not sure how long would it take for you to have any balance after you start mining. Maybe it's minutes or maybe it's days? If you figured it out let me know. I'd like to know myself.
Thanks.